# Vertical column text in TableView

Tags: javafx, tableview

I try to create a table with javafx. The cell content is mostly short text or numbers but the column header is a long describing text. So I would prefer to rotate the text in the column header.
The code below works but the problem now is that the text in the header will be shortened (with ellipsis at the end) when the column width is reduced with the mouse.
Can this behaviour be 'switched off'? Any other proposals?

Here is my code:

```
public class TableRotHeader extends Application {

private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(TableRotHeader.class.getName());

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
    Group group = new Group();
    Scene scene = new Scene(group);
    stage.setTitle("Table with rotated header");
    stage.setWidth(800);
    stage.setHeight(600);

    TableView tableView = new TableView();
    TableColumn colA = new TableColumn("horizontal\ncol header");
    TableColumn colB = new TableColumn("");
    final int minWidth = 25;
    colA.setMinWidth(minWidth);
    colB.setMinWidth(minWidth);

    MyLabel l = new MyLabel("labeled attribute");
    l.setRotate(-90);
    l.setPrefHeight(150);
    colB.setGraphic(l);

    tableView.getColumns().addAll(colA, colB);

    group.getChildren().add(tableView);
    tableView.prefWidthProperty().bind(scene.widthProperty());
    tableView.prefHeightProperty().bind(scene.heightProperty());
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}
```

[image: ellipsis should be suppressed]

edit: both answers (from James_D and Mailkov) works great. 
I now want to group 2 labels to get 2 vertical lines. This causes a distance between them. 
A: How to get a reasonable distance (red arrow in screenshot)? This could be textheight * 1.2 or similar.
B: How to get a few pixels distance to the top and bottom of the labels (blue arrow)?

```
Label label1 = new Label("col 1");
label1.setRotate(-90);
MyLabel label2 = new MyLabel("col number 2 with a long text");
label2.setRotate(-90);
label2.setStyle("-fx-background-color: white; -fx-font-weight: normal");
Group g = new Group(label1, label2);
colB.setGraphic(g);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works perfectly for me now.
To get this result...
[image]

...i used the following code with vbox-padding and the blackOnWhite style:

```
public class TableRotHeader extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
    Group group = new Group();
    Scene scene = new Scene(group);
    scene.getStylesheets().add("com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/modena/blackOnWhite.css");

    stage.setTitle("Table with rotated header");
    stage.setWidth(800);
    stage.setHeight(600);

    TableView tableView = new TableView();
    TableColumn colA = new TableColumn("horizontal\ncol header");
    TableColumn colB = new TableColumn("");
    final int minWidth = 50;
    colA.setMinWidth(minWidth);
    colB.setMinWidth(minWidth);

    Label label1 = new Label("col 1");
    Label label2 = new Label("col number 2 with a long text");
    label2.setStyle("-fx-font-weight: normal");

    VBox vbox = new VBox(label1, label2);
    vbox.setRotate(-90);
    vbox.setPadding(new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5));

    Group g = new Group(vbox);
    colB.setGraphic(g);

    tableView.getColumns().addAll(colA, colB);

    group.getChildren().add(tableView);
    tableView.prefWidthProperty().bind(scene.widthProperty());
    tableView.prefHeightProperty().bind(scene.heightProperty());
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

}

Comment: Perfect, helped me really much. Note: In JavaFX 2, there's no constructor for VBox to use `new VBox(label1, label2);`, instead, `VBox vb = new VBox(); vb.getChildren().add(label1);` is available.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap the label in a `Group`:

```
    colB.setGraphic(new Group(l));
```

Comment: this works great - thx. please see my edit showing the issue i got now with two labels in a group.

Comment: Try putting them in a `VBox` and rotating the `VBox` (then wrap the `VBox` in a `Group`).

Comment: this also works - see my own answer. Using only a VBox (with two labels) does not really work. The group object does the trick. Is there a documentation somewhere about why and when using the Group?

Comment: See the [`Group` Javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Group.html): "if transforms and effects are set directly on children of this Group, those will be included in this Group's layout bounds"

Answer (score 1):

You can use setMinWidth() and setMinHeight() for MyLabel l